# Function call error in ethereum smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs

I am trying to call a ethereum smart contract function but it gives me error. It works perfectly fine with remix JVM environment but throws error with web3 provider. I am just trying to call a function but it is showing me different contract address , as if it has created new contract. Is there any problem with the contract ?

error :-

```
"Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0xac0800a862fb3f6864f2fadc354baa47b11279095ce1c1e130af5176c97140df",
  "blockNumber": 6369858,
  "contractAddress": "0xb7fcf989EDB79DAd87990DF85412DF116AC7406E",
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 2100000,
  "from": "0xf61343ef22bbccc7221dcda85c5a69219ea00c2b",
  "gasUsed": 2100000,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": null,
  "transactionHash": "0xab70d64929785cb3e718c78238575c3d21e9f4d4f5e481d26ca4069f269ae9d9",
  "transactionIndex": 0
}"
```

web3 code :-

```
const NODE_ADDRESS = config.web3Provider;
    const PRIVATE_KEY = reqdata.signerPriKey;

    const sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('path_to_contract', 'utf8').toString();
    const compiledCode = compiler.compile(sourceCode, 1).contracts[':PropertyContract']
    const abi = JSON.parse(compiledCode.interface);

    async function send(web3, account, transaction) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                const options = {
                    data: transaction.encodeABI(),
                    //gas: await transaction.estimateGas({ from: account.address }),
                    gas: 2100000,
                    gasPrice: 10000000000,
                };
                const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
                const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
                return receipt;
            }
            catch (error) {
                return error
            }
        }
    }

    async function run() {
        try {
            const web3 = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);
            const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(PRIVATE_KEY);
            const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, reqdata.contractAddr);
            const transaction = contract.methods.signAgreement(reqdata.signerPubKey);
            const receipt = await send(web3, account, transaction);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(receipt, null, 4));
            if (web3.currentProvider.constructor.name == "WebsocketProvider")
                web3.currentProvider.connection.close();
            if (receipt) {
                next(null, receipt)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            next(error, null)
        }  
    }
    run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `options` object passed to the `signTransaction` function, add this:

```
to: transaction._parent._address
```

Note that if this (which you have masked out) fails:

```
await transaction.estimateGas({ from: account.address })
```

Then the actual transaction will fail too.

So there is no point masking it out; you should investigate why your function reverts.

Comment: thanks a lot , it worked after adding "to".   1 more query is that should i use .call() or .sendTransaction() to call view only functions ? They needed to be signed ?
Again thanks a lot i really appreciate your help. I do know much about ethereum , i recently started on ethereum.

Comment: @PuneetKumar: You're welcome. No, you do not need to sign them with a private key, because they do not change the state of the contract (i.e., the state of the blockchain). They are therefore not considered transactions, just RPCs - remote process calls, where the remote process is the Ethereum node that you're communicating with. You should therefore use `.call()`.